# Perl Regular expression to match string contains alphabets/digits/dot

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match a string that contains alphanumeric,  digits and dot.

- Starts with alphabets [a-z|A-Z] followed by digits seprated by dot in
  between [1.2.3.5] and ends with digit only.

Some examples of what I'm trying to match:

```
my @patternsTomatch = (
 'SAN100.25.36.2',   # Valid string 
, 'DF1.2.3.5',       # Valid string
, 'BADPATTERN',      # In-Valid string
, '12BADPATTERN',    # In-Valid string
, '.DF1.2.3.5',       # In-Valid string
, 'SAN100.25.36.2.'  # In-Valid string
);

foreach my $pattern (@patternsTomatch) {
   if ( $pattern =~ /^([a-z|A-Z]+)(\d+\.)(.*)$/ ) { print " $pattern \n"; }
}
```

But above attempt is not working correctly?

Also, need a regular expression to match the fixed format string XC1.2.3.4_25 in seprate condition.

- Starts with alphabets [a-z|A-Z] followed by digits seprated by dot in
  between [1.2.3.5], followed by only one underscore and ends with only
  digit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might first match 1+ chars `[A-Za-z]+` (Note that you don't need the pipe in the character class) and then repeat matching digits with a dot in between:

```
^[A-Za-z]+\d+(?:\.\d+)+$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zju6G2/1)

---

To match an underscore and digits at the end, you could add matching an underscore and 1+ digits at the end of the pattern before asserting the end of the string:

```
^[A-Za-z]+\d+(?:\.\d+)+_\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fvsahx/1)

Comment: Thanks... solves my problem. Any chance you can help me matching string XC1.2.3.4_25 too!

Comment: I want to match XC1.2.3.4_25 as separate expression that doesn't match XC1.2.3.4 or SAN100.25.36.2

Comment: @LittleMagnolia Then you could match it at the end of the expression without making it optional https://regex101.com/r/fvsahx/1

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick responses. Solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something more like this:

```
my @candidates = (
  'SAN100.25.36.2',   # Valid string
  'DF1.2.3.5',        # Valid string
  'BADPATTERN',       # In-Valid string
  '12BADPATTERN',     # In-Valid string
  '.DF1.2.3.5',       # In-Valid string
  'SAN100.25.36.2.'   # In-Valid string
);

# store the pattern in a variable to get it out of the way 
# of the logic
my $pattern = qr/
    \A          # beginning of string
    [a-z]+      # latin letters, case insensitive
    \d+         # digits
    (?:         # groups of . and digits
        \.
        \d+
    )+
    (?:         # optional _ digits at end (or leave this group out)
        _
        \d+
    )?
    \z          # end of string
    /ix;        # /i - case insenstive  /x - expanded format

foreach my $candidate ( @candidates ) {
   if( $candidate =~ $pattern ) {
     print "$candidate matched\n";
     }
   else {
     print "$candidate missed\n";
     }
}
```

Comment: The OP added this comment when I suggested to make the `_\d+` part optional `I want to match XC1.2.3.4_25 as separate expression that doesn't match XC1.2.3.4 or SAN100.25.36.2` that is why I added 2 patterns.

Comment: And that's why I left the comment "(or leave this group out)"

Answer (score 0):

Made code as simple as possible

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my @match = grep { chomp; /^[a-z]+\d+(:?\.\d+)+(:?_\d+)?$/i } <DATA>;

map{ say } @match;

__DATA__
SAN100.25.36.2
DF1.2.3.5
BADPATTERN
12BADPATTERN
.DF1.2.3.5
SAN100.25.36.2.
XC1.2.3.4_25
```

output

```
SAN100.25.36.2
DF1.2.3.5
XC1.2.3.4_25
```

Comment: I have suggested the optional `_\d+` part, but the response of the OP was `I want to match XC1.2.3.4_25 as separate expression that doesn't match XC1.2.3.4 or SAN100.25.36.2 ` Btw, why do you want to match an optional colon `:?` ?

Comment: @The fourth bird -- it is not clear why OP mentioned separate pattern when it can be done in one. I made one pattern for both cases `_\d+` can present or not. We can not _to read_ mind of OP to understand what is the idea they following. Quite often the questions is not very well defined and a lot of assumption can be made on our part.